# Manage Image Submissions in WordPress

Tags: image-processing, wordpress, expressionengine

I have a client WordPress website that allows users to upload custom artwork from the front end.

I use TDO Mini Forms to create the submission form, but it doesn't seem to have options for file manipulation on upload. As a result, the images are often very large, sometimes in CMYK, and have various other issues.

I've managed the size issue, to some extent, using WP's media settings, but there are two issues that have vexed me:

1. It doesn't address the CMYK issue (which admittedly happens very rarely, but still prompts a call from the client).
2. WP doesn't discard the original image, which creates huge backup files.

Is there an extension out there that better manages submitted images? Even if it involves replacing the submission form (TDO Mini Forms works well, but has been unsupported for some time), I'm looking for any solution that meets this need.

IMO, the gold standard would be a WP equivalent to ExpressionEngine's [Safecracker](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker) + DevDemon's [ChannelImages](http://www.devdemon.com/channel_images/).

Is there anything out there? I can't be the only one looking for this.

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a plug-in called Imsanity (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/imsanity/).

It still doesn't address the CMYK issue, but it does manage the file sizes, which is the more pressing issue.

It also works retroactively, so if you already have large images on your site, you can bulk resize them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's exactly what you need, but this may help you out:

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm

It's integrated into this plugin I used some months ago for a client:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/photosmash-galleries/

Comment: That does basically the same thing as the TDO Mini Form I have in place, but doesn't address the issues I'm experiencing and is also discontinued. Thanks for the response, though.

Comment: Sorry it's not exactly what you searching for, just wanted to add a short note :-) ...   found this, too: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/ may be a workaround at the size issue (at least in chrome/firefox/browsers that can use all the fileapi-methods. )